# Flutter: Cómo forzar el cargue de datos en Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

Dentro del App, tengo una página (ListaAlimentarPage) que despliega una lista de registros. Estoy haciendo pruebas con varios celulares que escriben registros y veo que no todos los celulares obtienen el listado completo de los registros que se han escrito al mismo tiempo, supongo que esto sucede porque el SDK de Firebase no consulta siempre la versión online de la Base de Datos. Por lo anterior en el App tengo que estar llamando la página constantemente hasta obtener el listado actualizado, lo cual hace que la experiencia no sea tan amigable.

Veo que hay aplicaciones que al hacer ScrollDown "forzan" la actualización de los datos y de esta manera se refrescan los registros. Cuál es la forma de hacer esto en Flutter? Cómo lo podría implementar? Interfiere en algo con el acceso Offline de Firebase?

La página que despliega la lista es la siguiente:

```
class ListaAlimentarPage extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final _prefs = new PreferenciasUsuario();
    
    final alimentarBloc = Provider.alimentarBloc(context);
    alimentarBloc.cargarAlimentar(_prefs.idEmpresa, _prefs.idEstanque);

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: _crearListado(context, alimentarBloc),
        bottomNavigationBar:  utils.crearBottom(context, 2),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _crearListado(BuildContext context, AlimentarBloc alimentarBloc) {

    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: alimentarBloc.alimentarStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AlimentarModel>> snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final alimentarList = snapshot.data;
            alimentarList.sort((a, b) => b.fecha.compareTo(a.fecha));
            return Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: alimentarList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) =>_crearItem(context, alimentarBloc, alimentarList[i]),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          } 
            return Center (child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/preloader.gif'), height: 200.0,));
        },
    );
  }

  Widget _crearItem(BuildContext context, AlimentarBloc alimentarBloc, AlimentarModel alimentar) {

      return Stack( 
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              
              child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text('${alimentar.nombreAlimentoFull}'),
                    onTap: () => null,
                  ),
              )
            ),
          ],
        );
  }
}
```

La consulta a la base de datos de Firebase la estoy haciendo con el método BLOC que llama al PROVIDER...

```
  Stream <List<AlimentarModel>>        get alimentarStream    => _alimentarController.stream;
  Stream <bool>                        get cargando           => _cargandoController.stream;

  Future<List<AlimentarModel>> cargarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {
    final alimentar = await _alimentarProvider.cargarAlimentar(idEmpresa, idEstanque);
    // ahora hay que insertar estos productos al stream...
    _alimentarController.sink.add(alimentar);
    return alimentar;
```

Y en el PROVIDER, la consulta a Firebase la tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
  Future<List<AlimentarModel>> cargarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {

  final List<AlimentarModel> alimentar = new List(); 

  Query resp = db.child('empresas').child(idEmpresa).child('estanques').child(idEstanque).child('loteActual').child('alimentacion');

  return resp.once().then((snapshot) {

      if (snapshot.value == null) return [];
      if (snapshot.value['error'] != null) return []; 

      snapshot.value.forEach((id, alim){
        final temp = AlimentarModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(alim));
        temp.idAlimentar = id;

        alimentar.add(temp);
      });
      return alimentar;
  }); 
}
```

Comment: En teoría firebase es realtime si lo implementas bien, de otro modo puedes usas el RefreshIndicator para volver a cargar datos

Comment: Gracias... y como se si está bien implementado? El procedimiento que estoy usando para llamar los datos es correcto?

Comment: hice un video pero con Firestore : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogXEriEdMDU   ,  tienes que escuchar snapshots en un stream , y luego con un StreamBuilder lees los cambios

Comment: En el Streambuilder de _crearListado lo estoy haciendo,no es así?

Comment: tienes que usar el método `listen` para que se mantenga escuchando, revisa el ejemplo oficial : https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart#L85

Comment: Ok gracias, lo revisaré